# Titanium: New view after intent

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, notificationmanager

I'm building an Titanium application. At this stage I develop this only for Android.

My application needs to do the following: when the user is clicking on a button, there has to be send a notification. I checked the [Titanium Notificationmanager](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.NotificationManager) page, and they helped me out a lot. When the user is clicking on a button, an intent pops up.

Now for the second part of my application, I want to direct the user to a new screen (or view) from the notification intent. How is it possible to do this?

In the intent you need to specify the classname:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
    // Substitute the correct classname for your application
    className : 'com.appcelerator.notificationsample.NotificationsampleActivity',
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

How can I direct the user to a new screen? Do I need to make a new alloy controller? Do I need to make a new view?
Can somebody help me out? :)

Answer (score 2):

You could actually use the same (main) package/class of the app and listen to the `newintent` event (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity-event-newintent) and then present a certain view.

To start a new activity please read http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Intents-section-43287298_AndroidIntents-CreateanExplicitIntent